# Virtualbox rails server only accessible externally for some applications

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, installation, virtualbox

I have an xUbuntu(14.04) virtualBox(4.3.15) server running on Windows 7.  I have a 2 sites on the server and when I run rails server for either application it can be accessed internally at localhost:3000 without issue.  However, when I access one app externally from a browser on the windows machine at the [virtualbox ip]:3000 the site renders without issue and the other displays 'cannot connect'.  Additionally I can ping [virtualbox ip]:3000 for the one site, but the other will receive no response.  Just the [virtualbox ip] can be pinged successfully when either site has rails server running.

Both sites are Rails 4.2.0.rc2, Ruby 2.0.0, and WEBrick 1.3.1.

Is there something that needs to be setup specifically so that the 2nd site works?

Haven't been able to locate any differences between the two which might cause an issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Was able to determine what the issue was.  The one app was starting on `http://0.0.0.0:3000` which to my understanding means it is listening on all interfaces, while the other app was starting on `http://localhost:3000`.  The localhost app was therefore not listening for external requests.  The solution was to start the rails server with the following.

```
rails server -b 0.0.0.0
```

This binds the app to the 0.0.0.0 ip address and I can now access it outside of my virtualbox xUbuntu instance by using [vm ip address]:3000 as the url.